# Blood's Honor glitch/bug solution?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I go in Jorrvaskr, my active quest tells me to go down to the Jorrvaskr living quarters, and the quest arrow leads me to where Kodlak is usually sitting - but there is no one in the seat.
Kodlak is dead and everyone is "mourning" but when I speak to anyone in the companions they act as if nothing happened.

For example I have the option to train from them still and ask "Why did you join the companions?"

Will it still work for me if I start the quest to retrieve the helm of winterhold and run through driftshade refuge or use invisibility potions to get the helm without killing anyone? (I have a saved game right when I started Bloods Honor and before I have killed any witches).

Note: I have not cleared driftshade refuge and I have not completed the quest to find the helm of winterhold.

Comment: Are you playing on PS, Xbox, or PC?

Comment: I'm playing on pS3

Comment: Does the "Forever Mourning Bug" match  your problem?
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blood%27s_Honor#Forever_Mourning_Bug

Comment: If that means that everyone is mourning the people who got hurt and Kodlaks death but when u speak to them they go on as normal, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions are listed for this bug:

> Solution #1 - For adventurers who have not cleared Driftshade Refuge
>   or completed the quest to find the Helm of Winterhold.
>        You may get the bug if you have the quest to retrieve the Helm of Winterhold for the Jarl of Winterhold, under misc quests, but have not
>   completed the quest to retrieve the Helm. Load up on invisibility
>   potions and sneak through the Refuge (killing no one), retrieve the
>   Helm, and return it to the Jarl. Then return to Whiterun and Vilkas
>   should give you the next quest, Purity of Revenge.

> Solution #2 - For adventurers who have cleared Driftshade Refuge and
>   completed the quest to find the Helm of Winterhold
>
> Wait for 32 days before killing ANY witches for "Blood's Honor".
>   Driftshade Refuge will still read as "cleared" on the map, but the
>   enemies inside will have respawned at this point, allowing the quest
>   "Purity of Revenge" to start as normal when you complete "Blood's
>   Honor".

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blood%27s_Honor#Forever_Mourning_Bug